# Apt-get on a virtual server with no internet

Tags: iso, apt

I've been trying to install a GCC compiler on a Natty,10.04 64 Ubuntu server.

I don't have an internet connection on it, I can only transfer files to it indirectly.

I've tried mounting an image of the full DVD on it, successfully (I think)
by doing:

```
mount -o loop /tmp/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso /media/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64

apt-cdrom -d=/media/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64/ add
```

and I updated `fstab`

But when I tried to `apt-get` from it (all I need is a source from which I can `apt-get build essential`) it still tried to connect to the internet.

Also, when trying to install a package by running `./configure` I got:

> "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH"

How can can I do this without a connection to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

apt-get looks in /etc/apt/sources.list for the list of locations where to get packages.
(and possibly any files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d)

you added the cdrom location with the apt-cdrom command, but it seems you forgot to remove the default internetlocations
-> make sure you have commented out all the internet locations

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, you can install the packages one by one through `dpkg`. But I believe, someone will provide a better answer on apt usage.

Comment: I tried that, got stuck in a dead end with 2 dependent packages...

Answer (score 0):

If you have another identical machine where you did this already (Installing GCC compiler) then it is easy. `/var/cache/apt/archives/` is the path where the apt checks for the installables (`*.deb`). If it is not there it will try to download. So here is how I did some thing similar earlier - I had things in one of my machines and then I copied all the `.deb` files from that archives path to the new machines archives path. Also there is the sources path `/etc/apt/` which actually keeps information about the mirror and source list which may also have to be copied over.